# Image supposed to be black and white has intermediate values and can not be used as a binary mask

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Assuming we have this image that seems to be binary:

[image]

However, when reading with opencv via:

```
img = cv2.imread("myImage.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

We notice that its values vary:

e.g

```
array([  0,  16,  32,  48,  64,  79,  80,  95,  96, 111, 112, 127, 128,
   143, 144, 159, 160, 175, 176, 191, 192, 207, 208, 223, 224, 239,
   240, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Is there a safe way to convert it to a simple binary range ([0,1])?
There is no restriction for package to be used, it can be either opencv, pillow etc.

Comment: what about a simple threshold operation? https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: this can be done with `numpy.where` and nothing more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image's RGB channel is all of the zeros, color difference in the alpha channel

Get Alpha channel

```
img = cv2.imread("myImage.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_alpha = img[:,:,3]
```

Convert alpha channel to binary

```
thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(img_alpha, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Range in [0,1]

```
im_bw = im_bw // 255
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a threshold such as 127. Then define pixel values below the threshold as zero and above the threshold as 1. But I think you have another problem because the values of your image have a wide range (0 to 255). This is not consistent with the image you show.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has alpha channel and transparency

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

dir = sys.path[0]
im = cv2.imread(dir+'/img.png', -1)

im[np.where(im[:, :, 3] == 0)] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/img_without_transparency.png', im)

im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

min = np.min(im)
max = np.max(im)
bw = cv2.threshold(im, (min+max)//2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
print(np.min(bw), np.max(bw))  # 0-255

bw = bw/255
print(np.min(bw), np.max(bw))  # 0-1
```

So the white space is not really white:

[image]